# Reading off the stack in 8086 Assembly (16 bit mode)

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I would like to be able to push some values to the stack using normal ASM functionality..

e.g.

```
push ax
push bx
push cx
push dx
```

I would like to access these in any order using the stack frame.

Let's say I want to pop off these in order of C, B, A, D rather than just having to do...

```
pop dx
pop cx
pop bx
pop ax
```

What's the best/most efficient way to do this using SP/BP so that I can just grab things when I need them without having to keep pushing and popping for every use of the initial 4 AX to DX values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case of a true 8086, you can't use SP as a base register, only BP, so you need to copy SP to BP, then use BP +/- offset as the address of a stack based variable, such as

```
        push    bp
        mov     bp,sp
        push    ax          ;[bp-2]
        push    bx          ;[bp-4]
        push    cx          ;[bp-6]
        push    dx          ;[bp-8]
        ...
        mov     ax,[bp-4]   ;ax = pushed value from bx
        ...
        mov     sp,bp       ;restore sp
        pop     bp          ;restore bp
```

Comment: On a 80186, you definitely want to use `leave` instead of `mov sp,bp` / `pop bp`, for code-size reasons.  (And it's still fairly efficient on modern x86).  But true 8086 didn't have that instruction (http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html), so yes, this is a good example.